# PostgreSQL - how to query "result IN ALL OF"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I am new to PostgreSQL and I have a problem with the following query:

```
WITH relevant_einsatz AS (
    SELECT einsatz.fahrzeug,einsatz.mannschaft 
    FROM einsatz 
    INNER JOIN bergefahrzeug ON einsatz.fahrzeug = bergefahrzeug.id
),
relevant_mannschaften AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT relevant_einsatz.mannschaft
    FROM relevant_einsatz
    WHERE relevant_einsatz.fahrzeug IN (SELECT id FROM bergefahrzeug)
    )
SELECT mannschaft.id,mannschaft.rufname,person.id,person.nachname 
FROM mannschaft,person,relevant_mannschaften WHERE mannschaft.leiter = person.id AND relevant_mannschaften.mannschaft=mannschaft.id;
```

This query is working basically - but in "relevant_mannschaften" I am currently selecting each mannschaft, which has been to an relevant_einsatz with at least 1 bergefahrzeug.

Instead of this, I want to select into "relevant_mannschaften" each mannschaft, which has been to an relevant_einsatz WITH EACH from bergefahrzeug.

Does anybody know how to formulate this change?

Answer (score 1):

The information you provide is rather rudimentary. But tuning into my mentalist skills, going out on a limb, I would guess this untangled version of the query does the job much faster:

```
SELECT m.id, m.rufname, p.id, p.nachname
FROM   person        p 
JOIN   mannschaft    m ON m.leiter = p.id
JOIN (
    SELECT e.mannschaft
    FROM   einsatz       e
    JOIN   bergefahrzeug b ON b.id = e.fahrzeug -- may be redundant
    GROUP  BY e.mannschaft
    HAVING count(DISTINCT e.fahrzeug)
         = (SELECT count(*) FROM bergefahrzeug)
    ) e ON e.mannschaft = m.id
```

#### Explain:

- In the subquery `e` I count how many `DISTINCT` mountain-vehicles (`bergfahrzeug`) have been used by a team (`mannschaft`)  in all their deployments (`einsatz`): `count(DISTINCT e.fahrzeug)`

  If that number matches the count in table `bergfahrzeug`:  `(SELECT count(*) FROM bergefahrzeug)` - the team qualifies according to your description.
- The rest of the query just fetches details from matching rows in `mannschaft` and `person`.

You don't need this line at all, if there are no other vehicles in play than bergfahrzeuge:

```
JOIN   bergefahrzeug b ON b.id = e.fahrzeug
```

Basically, this is a special application of **relational division**. A lot more on the topic under this related question:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how to explain it, but here is an example how I solved this problem, just in case somebody has the some question one day.

```
WITH dfz AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT fahrzeug,mannschaft FROM einsatz WHERE einsatz.fahrzeug IN (SELECT id FROM bergefahrzeug)
), abc AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT mannschaft FROM dfz
), einsatzmannschaften AS (
    SELECT abc.mannschaft FROM abc WHERE (SELECT sum(dfz.fahrzeug) FROM dfz WHERE dfz.mannschaft = abc.mannschaft) = (SELECT sum(bergefahrzeug.id) FROM bergefahrzeug)
)
SELECT mannschaft.id,mannschaft.rufname,person.id,person.nachname
FROM mannschaft,person,einsatzmannschaften WHERE mannschaft.leiter = person.id AND einsatzmannschaften.mannschaft=mannschaft.id;
```